# Different Kurento API's Capability

Tags: kurento, jitsi

I was going through kurento API's there are three types, JAVA, Nodejs and Javascript API. I am trying to use javascript API, does any of you know that is it possible to have group audio/video calling, and audio recording with Javascript API?

Also, as an alternative I am trying out Jitsi-Meet, which provides all of the above functionalities (except recording), is it difficult writing that functionality for Jitsi-meet or to customize it's UI?

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi developer here.

We have recording capability now, have a look at the jibri project. In terms of customization, Jitsi Meet is a web application with a bunch of CSS, and recently some React (we are migrating to it) so it should be relatively easy to customize for web developers.